# Load Email:Pass from a file

Tags: python, file, email

```
file = open("list.txt", "r", encoding="Latin-1").readlines()
file = [combos.rstrip() for combos in file]
for lines in file:
    data = lines.split(":")
    password = data[1]
    email = data[0]

print(email)
```

my list.txt looks like this:

```
test@gmail.com:Password1
123@gmail.com:Pass
842398412@Gmail.com:daidn
```

Output:

```
842398412@Gmail.com
```

I want it to move down to the next line each time I call email so, for example,
if I do `print(email)` I want it to output the first email in the list and if I call it again I want to output the second one. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `print` *inside* the loop?

Answer (score 0):

To look for the *next* line when running your code again, your code needs to keep track of what line it should be looking for. You can write a generator that keeps track of this for you, and you can call `next()` to get each next value in the list.

```
def file_lines():
    lines = open("list.txt", "r", encoding="Latin-1").readlines()
    for line in lines:
        yield line

generator = file_lines()
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
```

Alternatively just store it in a list and don't use a generator at all

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

- Don't recommended to open files without context managers
- You can do a function yield...
- You can convert a list to an iter.

I prefer last:

```
with open("list.txt", "r", encoding="Latin-1") as file:
    content = [i.rstrip() for i in file.readlines()]
    for lines in content:
        data = lines.split(":")
        password = data[1]
        email = data[0]
        items.append(email)

emails = iter(items)
```

And then `next(email)` for iterate above it

Good luck